# Problema enviar datos a Modal PopUp

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, modal

mi problema es que tengo una dataTable con un boton editar en cada fila, al momento de presionarlo quisiera que los datos de esa fila se transporten al modal popUp, pero actualmente no lo realiza, le envio el codigo:

HTML BOTON PARA ABRIR EL MODAL

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" data-mytitle="{{$listado->rut_alumno}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-editar-alumno">
                     <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </button>
```

MODAL EDITAR

```html
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal-editar-alumno">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Crear Alumno</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- cuerpo pop-up -->
                 <form action="/editarAlumno" method="post">
         <!-- sistema de seguridad analiza los hacks head, get, options para evitar injection -->
          {{ csrf_field() }}
         <!-- fin -->
<!-- cuerpo del popup-->
      
                <!-- ./ cuerpo pop-up-->

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
         
        
</div>
```

```js
<!--scripts de modal pop Up-->
<script>
  $('#modal-editar-alumno').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var id = button.data('mytitle') 
  var modal = $(this)
 
  modal.find('.modal-body #id').val(id);
})
</script>
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme por favor.
Como mencione anteriormente, los datos que estan en mi tablas no aparecen en el modal.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

PD.: No coloque el cuerpo del popUp por que lo encontre irelevante, pero son en total 6 inputs